# 3D Model with Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin.android, 3d-modelling

I'm interested in adding a 3d model into my Android app which is being developed in Mono with c#. The model will be developed with a tool like Blender. An example of the interaction with the model would be clicking a "smile" button and initiating the models smile sequence. Is there a clever "container" for this type of media? I only need to show the user pre-determined routines - they won't be creating new ones.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make use of [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) library, which is `C#` wrapper over `OpenGL`. 
You may want to have also some importers for the file format you're going to operate on.

This is just an exaple of a simple Cube, from xamarin site itself:

[Hello GLCube](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello__glCube)